Reference request: stability of the barycenter under the logarithm map in Hadamard spaces
Let $X$ be an Hadamard space.
For $p\in X$ let $\log_p:X\to T_pX$ be the logarithm map that maps points in $X$ to the corresponding points in the tangent space $T_pX$.
Let $μ$ be a Borel probability distribution on $X$ with a second moment.
The push-forward distribution $\mu_{\#\log_p}$ on $T_pX$ is defined as $\mu_{\#\log_p}(A)=\mu(\log_p^{-1}(A))$. Let $b(μ)\in X$ the barycenter of $μ$, and $b(\mu_{\#\log_{b(\mu)}})\in T_{b(\mu)}X$ the barycenter of $\mu_{\#\log_{b(\mu)}}$.
Claim:
$b(\mu_{\#\log_{b(\mu)}})$ is the cusp of $T_{b(\mu)}X$.
The above claim seems sufficiently simple and useful to be observed before. I'm looking for a reference or references where it is stated and proved.
Thanks in advance.

I would write that it follows since $(d_x\mathrm{dist}_p^2)(v)=-2\cdot\langle\log_xp,v\rangle$.

What does "the cusp" mean here?
